# VB.Net Multithreading - Event Not Firing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, events, thread-safety

I've got this code, and let's say I am iterating over 100 items.  The first time I iterate over the list, the ProxyTested event fires 100 times.  Great, that was easy.

Now comes the annoying unknown bug currently giving me a headache, if only it would give me an exception too, then I could probably figure out whats going wrong much easier.

Here it is: The second time I iterate over the list, and each time after, the ProxyTested event fires 99 times.  What happened to 1 of my iterations?

***P.S.*** For my project, Tasks throughput is much slower than spawning say 500 of my own threads, so because of that reason I don't want to use them.  Just saying that before the inevitable suggestion. It may not look so pretty, but it runs very, very fast compared to creating a list of Tasks and passing them into Task.WaitAll, which is admittedly much easier on the eyes.

***P.S.S.***
Also, before the use a Concurrent Collection suggestion that is also inevitable, need to use a DataTable here, because I am also using SqliteDataAdapter.Update in this project, which only takes a DataTable or array of DataRow's.

```
Dim counter as integer = 0
For i = 0 To ThreadCount - 1
            Dim t As New Thread(Sub()
                                Do

                                    Dim item As DataRow = Nothing
                                    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
                                    SyncLock lock
                                        If counter > Proxies.Rows.Count Then
                                            Exit Do
                                        End If
                                        item = Proxies(counter)
                                        Interlocked.Increment(counter)
                                        Dim judge As DataRow = validJudges(rnd.Next(0, validJudges.Count))
                                        Dim proxy As String = item("ip") & ":" & item("port")

                                        req = HttpWebRequest.Create(judge("url"))
                                        req.Proxy = New WebProxy(proxy)
                                        req.Timeout = Timeout
                                        Debug.WriteLine(counter)
                                    End SyncLock

                                    Dim statusText As String = ProxyTest.GetStatus(req, "<title>AZ Environment variables 1.04</title>", externalIp)

                                    SyncLock lock
                                        item("statusText") = statusText

                                        If statusText = "Valid" Then
                                            Interlocked.Increment(ValidCount)
                                        Else
                                            Interlocked.Increment(InvalidCount)
                                        End If
                                        Interlocked.Increment(CompletedCount)
                                        RaiseEvent ProxyTested(item)
                                    End SyncLock

                                Loop
                                mre.Set()
                            End Sub)
            t.Start()
        Next
        mre.Reset()
        mre.WaitOne()
```

Comment: I note that you have an exit condition within the loop on `counter` which is protected by a lock, and the `While` loop effectively has the same condition on `counter` but is not protected by a lock.  Is there any particular reason that the `While` loop isn't an infinite loop, relying on the existing test within it to take care of termination?

Comment: @Craig Hi, the exit condition I added probably incorrectly, but the reason for it was because counter was becoming greater than Proxies.Rows.Count, which I was hoping the loop wouldn't run if that was the case, because of the While counter < Proxies.Rows.Count condition.  That exit condition was to gracefully exit when that was happening, but I had a feeling I was missing something when I added it.  

I'm a bit over my head here to be perfectly honest, but I feel I'm not too far off from what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Craig As far as why I am not running an infinite loop, well, my naive answer is that I don't want it to run infinitely :P  I only want it to run until the work is complete.

Comment: My point is (and I'm no multithreading expert), you're trying to figure out why you're getting unexpected behavior.  The first thing I look for is something that isn't protected, and the something that isn't protected is the condition on the `While` loop.  You have the exit condition (protected) within the loop, so my own temptation would be to make the loop nominally infinite and rely on the protected test to terminate it.

Comment: @Craig Well if you don't mind posting some psuedocode for me as an answer, if it works I can mark it.  If not it's cool though, appreciate the help.  So by infinite you mean like While True i'd imagine.  The sad part is I had this working earlier, refactored a bit to test something and broke something along the way :\

Comment: Exactly, `While True` or `Do` ... `Loop` with no condition in the `Loop` statement.  I'm making an educated guess, so I'd rather find out that it actually fixes your problem before I submit as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Re initializing my ManualResetEvent each time I called this method solved my problem :)

mre = New ManualResetEvent(False)

Previously mre was a global that was only initialized once during loading.